# How do you paste with vim without code being commented?

Tags: vim

Everytime I paste in vim, every line is commented out.

Is there a way around this?

Answer (score 189, accepted):

Before you paste, type this in normal mode:

```
:set paste
```

Then enter insert mode.  You will see the status bar say `insert (paste)`.  Paste your code.  Hit <kbd>ESC</kbd> to return to normal mode, and:

```
:set nopaste
```

You are no longer in paste mode.

Comment: To clarify, 'paste mode' turns off a lot of the auto-formatting and indentation features all at once, making it safe to paste large blocks of text without the content being munged.

Comment: Don't forget to check out 'pastetoggle', which makes it easier to do these to steps.  For instance, I have:

set pastetoggle=<Insert>

This way before I paste text I just hit the <Insert> key.  Then when I'm done I press it again.  This is very convenient since I paste text with Shift-<Insert>

Comment: Add the `pastetoggle=<F2>` to your `.vimrc` so you don't have to set it each time. As mentioned about you can map this to a different key if you want. `<Insert>` might be ideal since by default it toggles replace mode. Which IMO is garbage.

Answer (score 44):

Or, to avoid having to turn `paste` on and off, just *put* the text. Rather than going into insert mode and pasting, in command mode type:

```
"+p
```

The `+` buffer corresponds to the system clipboard.

If you insist on using `paste`, I'd suggest mapping something to toggle it. For example, `:set pastetoggle=<F2>` (wow, didn't realize there was a special option for that)

Comment: @rampion: Yeah, that's what I originally mentioned, but took it out in favor of `pastetoggle`.

Comment: 'pastetoggle' exists b/c you can't use an insert mode map to turn 'paste' back off--having 'paste' on disables on insert mode mappings.

Comment: this did not work for me? any overriding for this not to work?

Comment: It is also important avoid clipboard hacking security issues: http://thejh.net/misc/website-terminal-copy-paste in my case: `inoremap <C-R>+ <C-R><C-R>+`

Comment: When I run "+p, nothing happens?

Comment: This will work for a local computer only. When you use ssh – there's a different paste buffer on a remote server.